# UPDATE SET gets MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Hi i have a reads counter, but i always get an MySQL error:

MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''reads') VALUES ('2') WHERE id = '20'' at line 1

```
    $reads = $row['reads']+1;
    $newsid = $row['id'];                             

    if(!$query = $db->query("UPDATE cmsss_news_articles SET reads = '$reads' WHERE id = '$newsid'")) {
    echo "<center><b>Error, cant update row</b></center>";
    }
```

Can you please help me where is the mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reads` is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Escape it with backticks.

```
UPDATE cmsss_news_articles 
SET `reads` = '$reads' 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also loose the increment variable to gain some performance and simplicity.

```
    $newsid = $row['id'];                             

    if(!$query = $db->query("UPDATE cmsss_news_articles SET `reads` = `reads` + 1 WHERE id = '$newsid'")) {
        echo "<center><b>Error, cant update row</b></center>";
    }
```

Comment: Despite being a correct answer, code only answers aren't great for learning __why__ something didn't work. You should explain why adding backticks made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Reads is a reverse key word in MySQL, hence put that in backquotes.

try this:

```
if(!$query = $db->query("UPDATE cmsss_news_articles SET `reads` = '$reads' WHERE id = '$newsid'")) {                                                ^^
    echo "<center><b>Error, cant update row</b></center>";
    }
```